# Overdrive voltage and Early effect in MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, theory

Can anyone explain to me if there is the Early effect in MOS transistor then the Early effect affects the expression for VOV which is \$VOV=\sqrt{\frac{2ID}{kn'(W/L)}}\$?

Comment: This is mentioned in **any** decent book about MOS transistors but anyway: The Early effect or **Base-width modulation** only happens in Bipolar transistors. In MOS transistors there is a similar effect (which I would never call Early effect) called **Channel length modulation**. It basically lowers the output impedance when the transistor is used as a current source.

Comment: Yes, its the \$( 1 + \lambda V_{DS} )\$ you see in the equation for drain current in saturation.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298829/common-drain-jfet-output-resistance-problem/299030#299030