IRFZ44N Datasheet read value problem
I'm having trouble with reading values from datasheet of IRFZ44N.
How can I find the value of Vth or K-B(UnCox*W/L) value at an arbitrary operating point?
I want to use MOSFETs in my design but can't find values unlike the textbooks.
Can you explain this to me or show an example?

Why tag BJT, amplifier? In addition to MOSFET, why tag FET, transistor? There is tag datasheet.

cant find enough tags, im newer. pls help instead this bhv.

$V_{GS(th) }$ is specified for gate connected to drain; 250 μA for power MOSFETs - how about measuring yourself? Did you search for, e.g., determine unCoxW/L? How did the results fail to provide what you are looking for?

But in that case we still do not know neither Vth or gm value. For example if i want to design an amplifier i should be able do determine the current Ids and the gm value.

You will not find these values in the datasheet. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321904/mosfet-biasing-problems/321928#321928  and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/678122/experimental-and-theoretical-determination-of-mosfet-threshold-voltage/678128#678128

In case i want to use it as an amplifier and place resistors like few kiloohms then Vgs gets down to levels around 3.5V and i have no information about the behaviour. How can i do the calculations ?
