# Equivalent Circuit of PMOS Amplifier circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier

I'm very confused on how to determine the equivalent circuit of this amplifier of common source in low amplitude signal mode.  Any help is appreciated :

[image]

Comment: Please explain your confusion so that folk answering will have some idea what knowledge you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent small-signal model will look exactly the same as if you would have used the NMOS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7XYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$v_{in} = v_{gs} + i_dR_S = v_{gs} + g_m v_{gs} R_S = v_{gs}(1 + g_m R_S)$$

$$v_{out} = -i_d R_D = -g_m v_{gs} R_D$$

So the voltage gain is:

$$\frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}} = \frac{-g_m v_{gs} R_D}{v_{gs}(1 + g_m R_S)} = -\frac{g_m  R_D}{1 + g_m R_S} = \frac{R_D}{\frac{1}{g_m} + R_S}
$$

Or you could use this equivalent circuit if you do not like the idea that we have the same small signal model for PMOS and NMOS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgLMJs.png)</sup>

Comment: but where is the output resistance the one \$r_0 = (\frac{\partial i_d}{\partial V_{SD}})^{-1} \$ also why is this called common source where the source isnt connected to the ground?

Comment: I have added ro (output resistance) into schematics.  We still call this CS because the input is at the gate and the output is at the drain.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

Comment: why is \$ r_0 \$ connected that way shouldnt it have also its own ground link?

Comment: \$r_o\$ models the channel length modulation (Vds voltage due to channel length modulation will have a small effect on the drain current).  Thus, \$r_o\$ is a resistance between the drain and the source terminal. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298829/common-drain-jfet-output-resistance-problem/299030#299030

Comment: also since we have a PMOS in this case why did u write \$ V_{GS} \$ instead of \$ V_{SG} \$ ?

Comment: Why should I use Vsg if I can use the same small-signal model for NMOS and PMOS?  What difference does it make?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149003/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-g36).